# how to import and register a car in Hungary?

Tags: netherlands, passport, customs

for example, we bought a 2008 ford mustang GT-CS in the Netherlands. we deregistered it and had temporary registration number plates issued. we drove it through germany and austria.

so, can anyone tell me the import, insurance and registration process in Hungary?

is it possible to register a car in Hungary as a non-resident? (i have my schengen visa issued on my turkish passport).

Answer (score 1):

[Anglo Info](https://www.angloinfo.com/how-to/hungary/transport/vehicle-ownership/importing-a-vehicle) states that car registration in Hungary requires both an address card and tax number, neither of which a non-resident would have.

> Foreign residents in Hungary can use their car for up to six months, after which registration is obligatory. To register a foreign car, a person must have both a tax number (Adószám) and an Address Card (Lakcímkártya). Registering a foreign car is quite expensive and the process can take up to a week. There are several agents specialising in the paperwork involved.
>
> In addition, owners of cars registered outside the EU also have to pay duties when importing a vehicle.
>
> **Technical Test**
>   The first step in the registration process is having the car checked at a technical test station. Only a car which meets European standards can pass the technical test and be imported into Hungary. The current environment standard is the Euro 4 and the car must have a catalytic converter.
>
> If a car fails the technical test, it can either be brought up to standard or used for spare parts.
>
> There are two certified test stations (Járm?honosításra Felhatalmazott Vizsgálóállomás) in Budapest:
>
> - At: 1033 Budapest, Mozaik u. 5
>     Tel: (01) 430 2718
> - At: 1195 Budapest, Vas Gereben u. 2-4
>     Tel: (01) 348 2060
>
> An appointment, which can be booked over the telephone, can take a few hours and includes the following steps:
>
> - The registration procedure is started
> - The car is tested for safety
> - The vehicle's documents are checked
> - Payment of the fee for the test
>
> The following documents are required:
>
> - ID card or passport
> - Address Card
> - The car's original registration papers. If the car is from outside the EU, then an official translation is required
> - Proof that the car is no longer registered in the country of origin. If the car is still registered in the country of origin, the Hungarian authority can start the deregistration procedure
>
> **Registration Tax**
>   If the car passes the technical test, then the next step is the customs office where registration tax is issued. This tax is calculated according to the following criteria:
>
> - Age of the car
> - Size of the engine
> - Fuel type
> - To calculate registration tax: [Click here](http://www.euvonal.hu/)
>
> If the car is being imported from outside the EU, duties are issued as well. If the car is new, VAT (ÁFA) of 27 percent is also due.
>
> - To find the nearest customs office: [Click here](http://nav.gov.hu//data/cms278746/59_2._fuzet_NAV_VP_Foigazgatosagok_es_Igazgatosagok_kozerdeku_informacioi.pdf) (PDF)
>
> Once Customs has calculated all the taxes and duties, the amount has to be paid, generally by bank transfer. It is advisable to use OTP bank as it is the bank of the Tax Office (NAV) and the transfer is instant. Most Customs offices have "mini banks" on their premises. Once the payment is received, Customs issues the necessary papers for registration.
>
> The final step is to go to the local Office for Administrative and Electronic Public Services (Önkormányzati Okmányiroda) where the car can finally be registered.
>
> New number plates and registration papers (forgalmi igazolvány) are issued on the spot, while a registration card (gépjármu törzslap) is sent later by post.
>
> There is a fee for the registration papers and the number plates.

Comment: This is *hopelessly* outdated. I will try to find a more up to date English version. To start with, the technical test is no longer a requirement if it has a recent enough EU technical test then a simpler and cheaper review is enough.

Comment: @chx ...THANK YOU, as my languages don't include Hungarian and, if you feel it is cleaner, go ahead and do it right in my answer, as an edit... it will be a co-answer collaboration.

Comment: It won't be. Answering this in an up-to-date way in Engish is beyond my capabilities. This is only slightly http://www.kormanyhivatal.hu/download/a/0e/41000/K%C3%BClf%C3%B6ldr%C5%91l%20sz%C3%A1rmaz%C3%B3%20k%C3%B6z%C3%BAti%20j%C3%A1rm%C5%B1vek%20forgalomba%20helyez%C3%A9se.pdf outdated and in Hungarian. Not sure whether there is even an up to date Hungarian document! One of the authorities named in this doc has been renamed / merged end of 2016.